# Android - How does cursor loader know underlying dataset has changed?

Tags: java, android, adapter, loader

I am trying to learn Android programming and have been working through the Udacity Sunshine app.

There is something that is confusing me. I have a content provider which does the inserts, deletes, selects etc, I have a cursor loader which is also a fragment and I have a cursor adaptor, most of it makes sense except for how the loader knows that the data has changed.

In the update method of the content provider it does this which I assume is notifying something that the data has changed:

```
if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
```

The loader gets set up in the onCreateLoader method:

```
return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            weatherForLocationUri,
            FORECAST_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
```

The URI is different for the load to the one used for the update though so how does the loader know the data has changed underneath??

The adaptor has a handle on the current cursor that was loaded as it is set up in onLoadFinished:

```
mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
```

Finally the list view itself has a handle on the cursor adapter:

```
mListView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
```

I just dont see how through this mechanism the loader knows the data has changed and how it informs the adaptor to instruct it to redraw the UI?

Also if any of my understanding of this is wrong please correct me!

Comment: `CursorAdapter`  has nothing to do with it, see http://codeshare.io/wJYDr, when you click the button you will see that your loader reloads new data

Comment: Yes I understand that, as I said the video and API both say you CAN leave the observations to the loader. I am not asking about this I am asking about the mechanics of observation. Nevermind, I will just assume that it is down to some sort of observer pattern and it is all handled magically for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors register themselves as notify for decedents, which means when the root URI is notified of a change, decedents of the URI are also notified, decedents can be anything with additional path information.

Comment: Cheers Steve that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont think I will get the true mechanics of this but as the API states:

"The Loader will monitor for changes to the data, and report them to you through new calls here. You should not monitor the data yourself. For example, if the data is a Cursor and you place it in a CursorAdapter, use the CursorAdapter(android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor, int) constructor without passing in either FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY or FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (that is, use 0 for the flags argument). This prevents the CursorAdapter from doing its own observing of the Cursor, which is not needed since when a change happens you will get a new Cursor throw another call here."

I can take it as a given that is just done for me and that whenever the data underneath changes then a new call to onLoadFinished will be triggered which in turn calls:

```
mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
```